# Random iteration in loop for printing characters present in list randomly

Tags: c#, loops, random, foreach

I have to loop through number 0-9 and characters A-Z but I want to loop through each element but randomly. I have tried below approach. Is there any better approach you can suggest.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Random r = new Random();
                var listOfAsciiForNumbers = Enumerable.Range(48, 10).ToList();
                var listofAsciiForAlphabets = Enumerable.Range(65, 26).ToList();

                var asciiList = new List<int>();
                asciiList.AddRange(listOfAsciiForNumbers);
                asciiList.AddRange(listofAsciiForAlphabets);

                foreach (int i in asciiList.OrderBy(x => r.Next()))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine((char)i);
                }
            }
```

Comment: What's wrong with your current approach?

Comment: What does "I want to loop through each element but randomly" mean?

Comment: @MatthewWatson  Not want to maintain  lists. I want to do all in same line with foreach.

Comment: @Enigmativity Loops goes in order but I want to randomize the loop but at the same time no elements should be missed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
Random r = new Random();

var ascii =
    Enumerable
        .Concat(
            Enumerable.Range(48, 10),
            Enumerable.Range(65, 26))
        .Select(n => (char)n)
        .OrderBy(c => r.Next());

Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, ascii));
```

Or more tersely:

```
var ascii =
    "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        .OrderBy(c => r.Next());
```

Or even:

```
Console.WriteLine(
    String.Join(
        Environment.NewLine,
        "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".OrderBy(c => r.Next())));
```